# Command to get available space on WedDAV resource?

Tags: http, curl, webdav

I'm uploading files with curl, and everything goes well when there is available space in the server. But when the file is greater than the free space an error messages is sent back.

For hours I've been digging here trying to find out if there is a curl/hhtp command to know if there is available space on a WebDAV resource.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A few servers support the extensions in http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4331.html.